# No module named - Running script from Terminal/IronPython

Tags: python, c#

When I try to open a scrpit using IronPython, I get an error: No module named 'config'

[ERROR MESSAGE Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXJ2R.png)

File structure for python project:

> Root
>
> > ConfigGenerator
> >
> > > **__config_generator.py**

> > **config.py**

**__config_generator.py:**

```
import config

CONFIG = config.Config()


def __main():
    # there are redundant to the question code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    __main()
```

And now **C# project**:

```
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProjectName
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private ScriptEngine _engine;

        public MainForm()
        {
            _engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void StartConfigGenerator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RunScript(@"Q:\Project\Python\Bots\Root\ConfigGenerator\__config_generator.py");
        }

        private void RunScript(string path)
        {
            _engine.ExecuteFile(path);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to import a python module you need it to be found using ironpython search paths, specifically you need to add `Root` folder to ironpython's search paths as follows.

```
_engine = Python.CreateEngine();
var paths = _engine.GetSearchPaths();
paths.Add(@"Q:\Project\Python\Bots\Root");
_engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
```